# Capture Checkbox Values In PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm having a couple problems and I think they are all somewhat interconnected.

brief summary of what i'm attempting to do.  I'm taking a sql query and i'm looping through the results to build a users table.  Then what i'm trying accomplish is for an admin to be able to activate and suspend users by a simple button click. With that being said, let me show the issues i'm having.

1) I'm having issues defining the input type so that each rows checkbox value attibute is the same as that users db id.  Then table is constructed inside a while loop using syntax similar to `$var .= whatever; var .= whatever2;` etc which is how the check box is placed at the beginning of each row.

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id='' value=\"{$row['memberid']>\" />
```

2) I'm having issues capturing the values of which check boxes are checked. This code appears after the end table tag but before the end form tag

```
$checkBox = $_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++){
    $sus_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn='1' WHERE id='$sus_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
if($result){
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=somepage.php\">";
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Do you "see" the checkboxes?I did not when i tried your code..

Comment: 1. Can you post the actual PHP code, not just a stub? 2. Can you post the actual HTML code you've got? 3. Can you post `var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);` result?

Comment: I can post the code the builds the table, and yes, i see the check boxes :)

Comment: Col: Shrapnel, correct to initial statement... I see: array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "" }

Comment: Col: Shrapnel, the variable dump helped me see which values were being assigned to what array index.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think i have figured it out further.

1) to answer the first question i asked:

```
$usertable .= "<td style=text-align:center;> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checked[]\" id='' value={$row['member_id']} /></td>";
```

The rest worked itself out!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try check the examples in the following link.

```
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-checkbox-array-in-form-handling-multiple-checkbox-values-in-an-array.html
```

And also mention different "name" for checkbox. Check the value is properly closed with braces {}and brackets(),[]..

Comment: The table is too big for these text areas,but i can paste some of it...`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b_result)){
    $usertable .= "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#CDCDCD'; this.style.color='#000000';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#123456'; this.style.color='#FFF';\">";
    $usertable .= "<td style=text-align:center;> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checked[]\" id='' value=\"<?php echo $p_i;?>\" /></td>";
    $usertable .= "<td> {$row['member_id']} </td>";
    $usertable .= "<td> {$row['firstname']} </td>";
    $usertable .= "<td> {$row['lastname']} </td>;`

Comment: ugh, thats ugly... sorry still trying to get use to this interface.

Comment: I answered my own question, but i'm unable to update because my rating is < 100, here is what i said: `    $usertable .= "<td style=text-align:center;> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checked[]\" id='' value={$row['member_id']}; /></td>";
`

Comment: Once the value attribute was fixed i was able to properly write the correct code to update my tables:  `    $sql = "UPDATE members SET xIsActive=1 WHERE member_id=$sus_id ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    // if successful refresh admin page
    if($result){
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=administrate.php\">";
    }
   
    mysql_close();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $checkBox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++){
        $sus_id = $checkbox[$i];
        //$sql = "UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn='1' WHERE id='$sus_id'";
        //$result = mysql_query($sql);
        //mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Value ==>"."$sus_id"."<br/>";
    }
}
?>

<form method=post action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id='' value="1" /> 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id='' value="2" /> 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id='' value="3" /> 3
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="22">
</form>
```

Also what you realy want to do by this line

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: The sql stuff is code i'm adding to perform the suspends and activates on user accounts, but i prematurely posted that. Ignore it.